# Emgu Split Object

Tags: c#, emgucv

May I ask, how can I separate the detected object in a contour?

[image: 1]

below is my source code

```
Image<Gray, byte> imgOutput = imgInput.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(100), new Gray(255)); Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint(); Mat m = new Mat();

//Image<Gray, byte> imgOut = new Image<Gray, byte>(imgInput.Width, imgInput.Height, new Gray(0));

CvInvoke.FindContours(imgOutput, contours, m, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

if (contours.Size > 0)
{
    double perimeter = CvInvoke.ArcLength(contours[1], true);
    VectorOfPoint approx = new VectorOfPoint();
    CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(contours[1], approx, 0.04 * perimeter, true);  
    CvInvoke.DrawContours(imgInput, contours, 1, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    pictureBox2.Image = imgInput.Bitmap; 
}
```

Separated objects result.

Comment: I would just use System.Drawing methods to draw the polygon (i.e. fillpolygon) to a new image, using the original image as the image-brush.